# Weighted sampling with 2 vectors

Tags: matlab, random

(1) I have two column vectors.

```
                           Eg. x = [283167.778           
                                   *289387.207                
                                   289705.322]            

                               y = [9121643.314
                                    9098348.666*
                                    9099832.621]
```

(2) I'd like to make a weighted random sampling using these vectors: when I'll select the element 289387.207 in vector x, necessarily I'll choose the element 9098348.666 in vector y.

(3) Also, I have the weighted w vector for each element in vector x and y.

How can I implement this in MatLab?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean random selection or random weighing of the vector?

Comment: Hi. random selection! tks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For random selection:

```
sel_idx= randi(3);
outputx = x(sel_idx);
outputy = y(sel_idx);
```

for random weighing:

```
w = rand(size(x));
w = w./sum(w); % normalize
outputx = w(:)'*x(:);
outputy = w(:)'*y(:);
```